# FileNotFoundError on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
img = printscreen_pil
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
img = enhancer.enhance(2)
img = img.convert('1')
img.save('temp.jpg')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('temp.jpg'))
```

I want to read the image in order to convert it to text but i get the error system cannot find the file specified. I think it has to do with the working directory of the python. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I hope you can help me.

this is the complete error mssg.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pncor\Documents\pyprograms\bot.py", line 23, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('temp.jpg'))
  File "C:\Users\pncor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\pncor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\pncor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\pncor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: the image and your script should be at same directory ...

Comment: The error is pretty obvious; check if your picture is on the same directory as your python script because you refer it relatively

Comment: If you could post the complete error and indicate the line which causes it, helping would be easier. I'm guessing it's the "img.convert('1')" line that triggers the error because it's not finding a file named '1'. Maybe it's actually '1.jpg' or something like that? But I'm just guessing with insufficient information.

Comment: I saved the script with the same directory of the image tho :/

Comment: @PNC: confirm that you have actually installed `tesseract` on your system and that it is on your path. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46631036/21945 for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`tesseract`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) package does not seem to be installed on your system, or it is not found on your path. `pytesseract` runs the `tesseract` binary as a sub process in order to perform the OCR.

Use the package manager on your OS to install it, or refer the the [installation documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract#installing-tesseract). You are using Windows so check [this](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki#windows) out.

Also I don't think that it is necessary to write the enhanced image to file first, just pass it directly to `pytesseract.image_to_string`:

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```